# How to find a tag which has a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to find the tag which has `data-direction` attribute. Somehow it is always undefined. What I am trying to do is get the values of `data-direction` and `data-cellId`.
Any ideas?

```
var row = $('<tr data-cellId="' + cell.fatherId + '" data-direction="' + cell.direction + '"/>');
var nameColumn = $('<td class="port-name-col" data-cellId="' + cell.fatherId + '">' +cell.value.name + '</td>');
var btnColumn = $('<td class="port-btn-col"><button type="button" title="Remove" class="btn btn-default btn-xs x-button-icon btn-delete-port"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>');
row.append(nameColumn);
row.append(btnColumn);
```

EventListener

```
$(document).off('click', '.btn-delete-port').on('click', '.btn-delete-port', function (event) {
    var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
    //find tr element that has cellID attribute
    var tr = $(elem).find("tr.data-cellId");
    alert($(elem).parent().parent().html())
});
```

Comment: try using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: use this `$(elem).find(tr[data-cellId]);`

Comment: Do you append `row` to the DOM at any point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
var tr = $(elem).find("tr.data-cellId");
```

The `.data-cellId` part selects based on an element with that class. To look for an attribute, use `[data-cellId]` in your selector:

```
var tr = $(elem).find("tr[data-cellId]");
```

To then get the value of that attribute, you can use:

```
tr.attr('data-cellId');
```

Comment: mm it looks like i asked my question in a wrong way. I get still undefined when i check alert(tr.html()). the thing is "tr[data-cellId]" is not a child element of $(elem). But desperetly i need to find tr tag which has data-cellId.

Comment: Can you show an working (or in your case, nearly working) example of your code in a jsfiddle.net example? If the `tr` isn't a child of your $elem why even use `find()` on it? Maybe you could try just  `var tr = $('tr[data-cellId]')` instead?